# Error while installing sample data Magento2.4.3-p1

Tags: magento2, sample-data, magento2.4.3.p1

`bin/magento sampledata:deploy` executed perfectly without any error, when running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` I am getting following errors:-

> Unable to apply data patch
> Magento\GroupedProductSampleData\Setup\Patch\Data\InstallGroupedProductSampleData
> for module Magento_GroupedProductSampleData. Original exception
> message: Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly

Magento Version is 2.4.3-p1

Please help me with your ideas so that I can fix it.

Comment: see the my updated answer for install sample data.

Comment: Try `bin/magento module:uninstall --remove-data --clear-static-content InstallGroupedProductSampleData`

Comment: $ bin/magento module:uninstall --remove-data --clear-static-content InstallGroupedProductSampleData   executed above command results in following error :- 
Unknown module(s): InstallGroupedProductSampleData

Comment: @Bhavesh; tried doing it by cloning also, results in error in module Unable to apply data patch  Magento\BundleSampleData ....

Comment: @katajata Please follow my step which one provided in screenshot. simply and it's working. Also, I have provided the URL for reference.

Comment: Do not required this command: bin/magento sampledata:deploy

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the sample data - if you have sample data installed then first run this command `php bin/magento sampledata:remove`

See the below image with successfully install sample data

[image]

Comment: Its fresh installation; and commands executed were :-                          
bin/magento sampledata:deploy            (executed successfully)                                       bin/magento setup:upgrade                   (following error )                                           requirement is with sample data, so tried to reset with bin/magento sampledata:reset command still no luck.

Comment: you can run this command first then again run this command php bin/magento sampledata:remove

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-clone.html

Follow this URL, I have just install sample data in fresh magento installation and it's working.